# How to use logback in android?

Tags: android, logback

I followed this [article](https://wageeshaerangi.medium.com/logging-in-android-applications-with-logback-3736ea46e199) to setup logback.

> NOTE: I am using `logback`, not `logback-android`

project dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7'
implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.7'
implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.7'
```

xml configuration file `app\src\main\resources\logback.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="Logcat"
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%date %level %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="File" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>./log/test.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="Logcat" />
        <appender-ref ref="File"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Then use `logger` like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("qwdqwd")

    logger.debug("hello")

    setContent {
      AndroidcomposelatestTheme {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
          ArticleScreen2()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get a error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getModule()Ljava/lang/Module; in class Ljava/lang/Class; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Class' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.EnvUtil.logbackVersionByModule(EnvUtil.java:56)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at ch.qos.logback.core.util.EnvUtil.logbackVersion(EnvUtil.java:36)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:81)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:77)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:50)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:183)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:170)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:455)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:441)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:390)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at com.sage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:57)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8214)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8202)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4033)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4247)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.672  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.673  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.673  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2613)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.673  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.673  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.673  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8668)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.673  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.673  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
2023-05-22 09:47:22.673  4644-4644  System.err              com.sage                             W      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: does this link help you in any way ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405727/logback-log-debug-not-working

Comment: @inkredusk I don't think it's a device problem, I can use `logback-android` on the same device and it works fine.

Comment: Ok. Are all the classes for the logback-classic jar able to resolve properly ?

Comment: @inkredusk It should resolve the classes, the error appears in the `run app` phase instead of the compile phase. Apart from the code written in the question above, I am not using any `logback` classes

Comment: My understanding is that the `logback-classic` and `logback-core` should only be used in case of writing unit tests in Android. However, in actual code you need to use only `logback-android`. The quickstart section mentions the same over here https://github.com/tony19/logback-android

Comment: @inkredusk I know can use `logback-android`, but how to use `logback` directly without relying on `logback-android`?

Comment: Yes I understand but am not sure if it can be done without relying on `logback-android`. Will try to check the same from my side